# C# HttpClient PostAsync - Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, windows, network-programming, httpclient

I am working on a client application that send images as b64 string to a python server (Jetson Nano).
The particularity is that i have to code it in .Net4.0 for WinXP compatibility reasons.

When i connect the client computer directly in ethernet to the server everything is working like a charm.

**When i connect it through wifi and my local network, i reach a 40 seconds timeout as if the request was never send.**

It work on another computer then i think it is linked to windows configuration.

The main function that send the request is a task :

```
    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(string b64)
    {
        var options = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "b64", b64 },
                {"threshold",App.PredConfig.DetectionThreshold.ToString() },
                {"kernel",App.PredConfig.MedianKernelSize.ToString() }
            };
        var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options);
        var content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "text/HTML");
        return client.PostAsync(App.PredConfig.APIPath, content);
    }
```

In debug mode, i see that the task is "waiting for activation" when the timeout is reach.
[image]

***From the computer that cause problem :***

- I have a ping

[image]

- Manual telnet query on the good "port" gives a result.

[image]

But no reaction when i send the data though the code.

***From another computer with the same program :***

[image]

I don't know what's going on...
I'am even not sure that is is a problem with the code, maybe a problem with group policies on my professionnal computer but i need to identify the cause.

**Do you have any idea ?**

Thanks !

Comment: You should use `await` with `PostAsync`. And do not use blocking calls, like `Wait()` in async code. There is a `CancellationToken` for that

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It is encapsulated in a background worker, it is why i've choosed to code like that. I prefer for visibility. But do you think it can be the source of the problem ? This code works on some computer and not other. It is what is strange to me.